# can we use more than one parameters for a dart setter method .?

Tags: dart

Can we use more parameters in dart setter method?

Dart setter and getter methods.

Normally we use setter like below

```
class Student
{
     int  _age;
     void set  gettersetter(int a ) => _age=a;  //set method
     void get  gettersetter => _age;            //get method 
}


void main()
{
     var stu = Student();
     stu.gettersetter = 2 ;
     print(stu.gettersetter);
}
```

how i can  use setter method like below.

***void set gettersetter(int a, int b) => _age=a+b;***

Comment: The purpose of a setter method is to allow expressions such as `variable = value;` to be syntactic sugar for invoking the setter.  It doesn't make sense to have multiple values in an assignment, so it doesn't make sense for a setter method to accept multiple arguments.  If you want to set a variable based on multiple arguments, you will need to use a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A setter allows you to have your own code called when you write `o.x = 42`. It allows you to implement the interface of a (non-final) field without actually having a field, or to intercept the writes to a field. That is all.

If you want a single method to be invoked with two arguments, you'll have to use a plain method `void setAgeSum(a, b) { _age = a + b; }`.

Comment: Thanks.. Irn., I appreciate your answer